# Doing pattern matching with REGEX in SED results in unterminated `s' command

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a csv file with data in with (which has : as delimiter). An example line is would be,

```
Vinh Tranh:438-910-7449:8235 Maple Street, Wilmington, VM 29085:9/23/63:68900
```

Now I need to print all lines that have 11 or 12 after the 3rd `:` character. I wrote my own Regex but when I write this to `sed` command it doesn't work?

```
$ sed -n -E 's#(?:.*?\:){3}(11)\s*\/#p' datebook
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: Your sed starts with `s`. Are you trying to replace something ? You obvious use `#` as sed delimiter but starting with `s` the synthax should be `s#replace_this#with_that#`.  So if you are trying to replace something you are missing a `#`. if you just want to print a line matching your pattern, delete first `s` of your sed.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -n -E 's#(?:.*?\:){3}(11)\s*\/#p'
```

There are several issues with this command:

- `s` command is for substitution, don't use it for filtering
- when you need another delimiter for filtering, you have to escape the first one

  - and you still escaped the `/` anyway
- `sed` doesn't support non-capturing group or non-greedy quantifiers

  - and non-greedy isn't suited here anyway, since it will try to match as long as there *minimum* three `:` characters - you need a negated character class to restrict to first three `:` characters
- you need to anchor the search, otherwise it will match anywhere in the line, not just from start of line

Here's a solution based on your description of getting lines with `11` or `12` after the third `:`

```sh
sed -nE '/^([^:]*:){3}1[12]\//p'

# with different delimiter
sed -nE '\#^([^:]*:){3}1[12]/#p'
```

`grep` is simpler to use:

```sh
grep -E '^([^:]*:){3}1[12]/'
```

And `awk` is the best suited in my opinion, since this is a field based processing:

```sh
awk -F: '$4 ~ /^1[12]\//'
```

I haven't used `\s` in the above solutions, you can add if needed.

Comment: this solution of ^([^:]*:){3}1[12]\/ doesn't work. It only returns 4 lines whereas it should return 8 lines. When I try the same regex on regex101, it doesn't match the 11 or 12 as well, it matches the data before the 3rd :. Here's example data

James Ikeda:834-938-8376:23445 Aster Ave., Allentown, NJ 83745:12/1/38:45000
Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300

Comment: Note that regex101 doesn't support BRE/ERE, but this particular regex is okay to test. I just checked the two samples you posted in the comment, and they seem to work fine: https://regex101.com/r/SpKZoD/1

Comment: I checked the link you've sent me and it doesnt match the 11 or 12 it only matches the address that is before the ":".

Comment: and also skipping regex101, it doesn't correctly print all lines anyways